# How to Display module only front page in joomla 1.5.9?

Tags: php, joomla, e-commerce

I want to Display module only front page in joomla 1.5.9? in inner page it willl be invisible?

Answer (score 3):

As a developer or an administrator?

**As a template developer:**
If youre a developer, you can add your module in the template wrapped in the following tags:

```
<?php $menu = & JSite::getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
    -- module code goes here --
}
?>
```

**As a site administrator**
If you are a site administrator and only want to show the module on the homepage, open the module configuration, and then under menu assignment click on "Select Menu Item(s) from the list", then select on the home page of your site from the list of menu pages and save the module.

Answer (score 0):

In the module configuration you can assign it to a specific menu item. If you assign it to home it will be displayed only on the home page.